# Spring Security - 403 Forbidden for every role except ROLE_USER

Tags: java, spring

I am creating an application using Role based restriction to certain REST endpoints.

I have a Roles table, user_roles table and a users table.

ROLE_USER is working fine, and users with that Role can successfully access their pages. Even if I swap it around so that only ROLE_USER can access /admin/**, it works.

**However, when I try use ROLE_ADMIN on the admin page, it never works. It always redirects me to the 403 Forbidden page**

Security Config:

```
    @Bean
DaoAuthenticationProvider provider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsServiceImpl);
    provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    return provider;
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(provider());
}


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/banking/**").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .and()
        .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
        .and()
        .logout().permitAll()
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
}
```

}

MyUserDetails:

```
public class MyUserDetails implements UserDetails {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -2067381432706760538L;

private User user;

public MyUserDetails(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    Set<Role> roles = user.getRoles();
    List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Role role : roles) {
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role.getName()));
    }

    return authorities;
}
```

UserDetailsServiceImpl:

```
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userService.findByUsername(username);

    if(user == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
    }

    return new MyUserDetails(user);
}
```

}

Would appreciate any help as I've been stuck on this for a while. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure your custom user details service is being used?  If users always have the `USER` role assigned, it looks like some spring defaults are being used here.

Comment: Thank you so much, the problem ended up being another class was also implementing user details. I had two implementations and it wasn't working. I just had to delete the other implementation. The other implementation made it default for all users to have ROLE_USER, hence why it didn't work.